# What are some recent breakthoughs in computer science [>=~2020]?

Tags: research

What are some recent breakthroughs in computer science? I am especially interested in research which have received inadequate attention or attains significant improvements over previous approaches.

Comment: This sounds too broad to me.  Also, "inadequate" sounds like a matter of opinion.  See our [help/dont-ask].  Any community votes?

Comment: To my opinion, matters of opinion include *recent*, *breakthrough*, *science*, *research*, *adequacy*, *significance* and *improvement*.

Comment: The question is certainly not completely objective. This was inspired by the question "[What are the lesser known but useful data structures?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500607/what-are-the-lesser-known-but-useful-data-structures)" from SO which is also not objective but is never the less a useful resource. This question may be too broad. If there are specific changes you would like me to make, let me know. Otherwise, I can delete it.

Comment: Said SO question was posted in early 2009 when the rules of the network were a lot more lax. In fact, there were no "rules of the network" back then, because there was no "network", there was only SO. The second site was only launched in April 2009.